# Is there a quick way to display the source code at a breakpoint in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I've set a breakpoint in gdb, and I'd like to see the exact line of source the breakpoint is on, just to confirm it's correct -- is there a quick way to do this?

The "info b" command gives me information about the breakpoints, but it doesn't display source:

```
(gdb) info b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x00000000006c3ba4 in MyClass::foo(bar*)
                                                   at /home/user1/src/MyClass.cpp:1021
```

I can type "list MyClass.cpp:1021" to see the lines around this breakpoint, but I'm wondering if there's a shorter way. Googling and reading the gdb manual didn't turn up anything.

I know that if I'm executing the program and have hit the breakpoint, I can just type "list", but I'm asking specifically about the case where I am not  at the breakpoint (the program may not even be running).

Comment: I'd be very interested to hear if you got anywhere with this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `list` command to show sources.  `list` takes a "linespec", which is gdb terminology for the kinds of arguments accepted by `break`.  So, you can either pass it whatever argument you used to make the breakpoint in the first place (e.g., `list function`) or you can pass it the file and line shown by `info b` (e.g., `list mysource.c:75`).

Comment: So, there's nothing simple like "list b 1" (to list the source for breakpoint 1?)

Comment: No, but perhaps you could write one in Python if you were so inclined.

Comment: @Chad it looks like you can simply use `list` (no args) when you hit a breakpoint and it will print out surrounding code. Hitting the enter key again will show you subsequent code. That's about as intuitive as I can imagine!

Comment: It's not about when you hit the breakpoint. That's trivial and the default. It's about listing it when you are not at that point. So, no it's not as intuitive as you can imagine;) The Q even includes the fact he knows he can list the source at current execution point.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest one can get to this is by turning the history on (`set history save on`) and then press CTRL-R to do a reverse search for the former `list` command.

More specifically, change your workflow when setting a breakpoint. After each command like `b main` GDB shows the source file like `path/to/main.cpp, line 12`. Immediately use this information in a quick `list main.cpp:12`. To show this location later press CTRL-R and type "main".

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-History.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a way as follows, (at least in GDB 13.1+) from reading the following carefully:

```
help info break
```

First, display the breakpoint in question:

```
info break <breakpoint-number>
```

List the address of expression $_ (last displayed breakpoint):

```
list *$_
```

In short:

```
i b <bp-number>
l *$_
```